# FilePond with ReactJs, file input

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I want to save the File uploaded in [FilePond(using react)](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/getting-started/installation/react/) inside a Form, how to get the file from the form so that I can send it using Axios?

This is the Form, does `fileRef` holds the file?

```html
    <form onSubmit={handleFileSubmit}>
        <FilePond
          name="excel_sheet"
          server={server}
          labelIdle={message}
          maxFiles={1}
          acceptedFileTypes={[
            "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
          ]}
          credits={""}
          ref={fileRef}
        />

        <button type="submit" className="btn">
          Upload
        </button>
      </form>
```

This is form submit handler, what to put on axios second param to send the file?

```js
async function handleFileSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // hit api route to upload the file
    const file = fileRef.current;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
    // await axios.post("/api/file/upload-file", {}, config);
  }
```

Comment: I believe it's `fileRef.pond.getFiles()` best to log fileRef to console and see which property the FilePond instance is in.